# JAX-RS Web application + Wildfly 8 + ExtJS cannot access server method

Tags: rest, jax-rs, wildfly

I'm totally new in Java EE. I've studied some samples and quickstarts and wanted to build my own simple helloWorld application from scratch. I've implemented server side, but after deploying it on a server i cannot access methods using REST. On a final step I want to integrate Java EE with ExtJS but now I'm stuck on problem which I described. I've read tens of tutorials but they seem to be laconic. All I want to do is just simple helloWorld Application using Rest and integrate it with ExtJS. But I can't move on when I can't even access server methods by URL.

I've created new Dynamic Web Project in JBoss developer studio and switch JAX-RS support in project properties. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
package main;


import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;


import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/SimpleApp")
public class Controller extends Application {

    @Inject
    RestService helloService;

    @PUT
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON() {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "\"}";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON2() {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "\"}";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON3() {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "\"}";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public String getHelloWorldXML() {
        return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "</result>`</xml>";`
    }

}
```

RestService is simeple POJO class. It contains only 1 method which returns string with Hello+whatever you provide as a parameter.

When I enter in a browser http://localhost:8088/SimpleApp/json I only get NotFound or 405 Error: Method not allowed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post your Ajax call,that you have done from ExtJS?

Comment: ExtJs call is not important now. I have problems with simple call the server method using URL, so calling from ExtJs won't change anything.

Comment: what is your war file name,that is being deployed in server?

Comment: You mean archieve in deployments folder on the server? It's SimpleApp.war

Comment: can you try to access it like localhost:8088/SimpleApp/SimpleApp/json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my colleague I managed to solve problem.

```
package main;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/")
public class Controller {

@Inject
RestService helloService;

@PUT
@Path("/json/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "\"}";
}
```

RestActivator Class

```
package main;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestActivator extends Application {
    /* class body intentionally left blank */
}
```

RestService class

```
package main;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class RestService {

    public String createHelloMessage(String name) {
            return "Hello " + name + "!";
        }
}
```

With such a structure server responds and I can call method using ExtJs too.
@PathParam in Controller is used because I call this method from ExtJs model and after whole URL ExtJs sticks Id of an instance.

example of URL: http://localhost:8088/SimpleApp/rest/json

Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

First error is that 2 of your methods have the same path in the annotation.

Secondly, ruling out configuration errors as above, I can suggest that have a look at your web app. It itself will have a context root, please append that to the URL you are using and it should work.

so, url will be of format:

http://localhost:port/webcontextroot/SimpleApp/json

Comment: Both method have same path but both supports different method(GET,PUT),So no problem is here,Server can easily distinguish between these two.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what are you talking about this context root.